# Fill up a grid of divs as efficiently as possible (Screen space, not CPU)

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm making a page to display testimonials for a client of mine.  Some of the testimonials are short while others are long.  It looked kind of "blocky"... Here is a picture of what it actually looks like:

[image]

*(Please ignore the temporary repeated testimonials for the time being)*

After thinking it over a bit, I realized that it would look much nicer if everything kind of filled up the empty space a bit more efficiently, this is what I cooked up in my image editing program:

[image]

Does anybody know how to have it do something like this?  I've Googled around a bit but I can't quite figure out the best search term for something like this...

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Here is what it ended up looking like after the answers below.  Thanks guys!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [masonry jquery](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: You were the first to answer with an answer that is fully supported so I'll give the points to you.  I've edited my main post to include the final result.  Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind working with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a plugin called [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is *perfect* for this task. You might have to learn a little bit of jQuery to get it to work, but that shouldn't take too long if you follow the [somewhat-extensive tutorial](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html).

You can't do this with CSS because the only way to do this is with `float`s, but those only work horizontally. This plugin emulates a `float: top` style via jQuery, which is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, I'd check out this plugin:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [CSS3 multi-column layout](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) is made for.

Unfortunately, not many browsers support it yet so you may have to apply some cleverness to make it "not ugly" in other browsers. For example, you could just let the default take over and have each testimonial take up the full width - this isn't so bad to read through and is certainly better than the original layout.